# Matching everything except a specific series of characters to split a string

Tags: regex

I have a process that some data goes through that can split a field into multiple values, using Regex.

The current regex is:
[^,\s][^,]*[^,\s]*

An example string that it would split would be this:

0/Books,1/Books/Fiction,2/Books/Fiction/Sci-Fi

The output would be an array of values:
"0/Books","1/Books/Fiction","2/Books/Fiction/Sci-Fi"

It works great except when there is a comma in the values.

i.e.
0/Books, Magazines and Others/, 1/Books, Magazines and Others/Fiction/, 2/Books, Magazines and Others/Fiction/Sci-Fi/

Since my regex is splitting in a single character, it's splitting at each comma.  Instead, I want it to split at "/, " (forward slash, comma, space).

I cannot figure out how to do that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split on `/,`  or on a single comma:

```
\/,\s|,
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rC07kb/1)

Or else split on only `\/\s` without the alternation.

Comment: (\/,\s) sort of works except that I want the reverse, really.  When I run this, it only keeps the "/, ".  I want to negate that

Comment: @TerryChambers-Onix That is because you have to use a split function instead of matching. What is the tool or language?

Comment: @TerryChambers-Onix You can also use a capture group `(.*?)(?:\/, |$)` https://regex101.com/r/jvd2Qs/1

Comment: The example you gave, \/, |((?:(?!\/, ).)+) actually works well to detect where the individual values are.  I realize, however, that it will cause a problem for what I am ultimately trying to do since I actually need the trailing "/" to be preserved.  (FYI the tool I am used is a software product called Lucidworks Fusion).

Comment: @TerryChambers-Onix What is your goal? Matching, replacing? If I search here, there is an extraction, filter and replacement function right? https://doc.lucidworks.com/search?sort=&start=0&rows=10&q=regex&wt=json&fq=productVersion:(%225.4%22)

Comment: My goal is to split a single string value into an array using the https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/5.3/219/regex-field-replacement-index-stage which I am already using.  It works great, it's just that I have not been able to craft the correct regex expression to do what I need.

Comment: @TerryChambers-Onix This will keep the trailing `/` in the group 1 value `(?<=\/), |((?:(?!\/, ).)+\/?)` https://regex101.com/r/wpkbMi/1 or `(.+?)(?:(?<=\/), |$)` https://regex101.com/r/T9CKH1/1 To get a match only, you might try lookarounds as well `[^, ]+(?:(?:(?<!\/),(?! )|(?<!\/,) )[^, ]+)*` https://regex101.com/r/LZzvua/1 You can also split on `(?<=\/), ` https://regex101.com/r/VAKV8o/1